How can I update a native field of the task in Project Server using REST API?
I need to make a HTTP Request in my Power Automate flow to update de percentcomplete field of the task. I tried a lot of endpoints e body’s but nothing works.

Can you add screenshots and code you tried in body for reference? Are you getting any error while using your code?
